# Ford Fulkerson (Implementation C#)

Tags: c#

Me and my friend were trying to implement the following class. To be able to create a graph and find Ford Fulkerson.
The problem is, I don't know how to implement the augmented path method.
This is what I did so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace FordFulkerson
{
    class Network{
        private class Vector{
            public int capacity;
            public int volume;
            public Node destination;

            public Arete(int capacity, int volume, Node toNode){
                this.capacity=capacity;
                this.volume=volume;
                this.destination=toNode;
            }
        }
        private class Node{
            public int id;
            public List<Vector> neighbors;

            public Node(int i){
                id=i;
                neighbors=new List<Vector>();
            }

            public void connect(Node toNode, int capacity){
                neighbors.Add(new Vector(capacity,0,toNode));
            }
        }

        private List<Node> nodes;

        public Network(int size){
            nodes=new List<Node>();
            for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
                nodes.Add(new Node(i));
            }
        }

        public void connect(int from, int to, int capacity){
            Node fromNode=null;
            Node toNode=null;
            foreach(Node n in nodes){
                if (n.id==from){
                    fromNode=n;
                }
                if (n.id==to){
                    toNode=n;
                }
            }
            if (fromNode!=null && toNode!=null){
                fromNode.connect(toNode, capacity);
            }
        }

        private void AugmentChain(List<Node> path){
            foreach(Node n in chemin){
                // ??
            }
        }

        private void deepFind(Node source, Node destination, ref List<Node> path){
            if (source==destination){
                AugmentChain(path);
            }
            foreach(Vector v in source.neighbors){
               if (v.capacity>v.volume && path.Contains(v.destination)==false){
                    path.Add(v.destination);
                    deepFind(v.destination,destination, ref path);
                    path.Remove(v.destination);

                }
            }
            foreach(Node n in nodes){
                foreach(Vector x in n.neighbors){
                    if (x.destination==source)
            {

            }
                }
            }
        }

        public void FordFulkerson(int source, int destination){
            Node S=null;
            Node D=null;
            foreach(Node n in nodes){
                if (n.id==source){
                    S=n;
                }
                if (n.id==destination){
                    D=n;
                }
            }
            List<Node> path=new List<Node>();
            path.Add(S); 
            deepFind(S,D,ref chemin);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sorry if my question is not appropriate. But I really have no clue on how to implement this function.
Can someone please tell me what to do?
Thank You.

Comment: maybe instead of dumping your code on us, you should try to explain the logic behind it all and what and how is required to get as an outcome.

Comment: In the deepFind method we found the path that connects the source to the destination and passed it to the AugmentChain method to try to augment the vectors associated with the nodes in the path with the minimum capacity of each Vector, here I got lost trying to figure out what's next for this Ford Fulkerson algorithm

Comment: But what are you trying to do?? what should be the result?